# Multiple xpath expressions

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xpathnavigator

Can somebody help me to write this expression as it is driving me crazy!

Take this site for example http://www.jigsaw-online.com/

I'm trying to build up an expression where I can get all links under a category of my choice.

E.g. I want all four /a under New In

I can get the New In link via

```
//header//li[@class='nav-level-1-list']/a[contains(text(),'New In')]
```

I've then tried going up a level to then get all the links via:

```
//header//li[@class='nav-level-1-list']//li/a
```

but that doesn't work because it's still trying to find an anchor that contains 'New In'

How can I combine these two expressions together so I can get all the links under the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//header//li[@class='nav-level-1-list']/ul[preceding-sibling::a[contains(text(),'New In')]]//li/a` (did not test it, has nothing to run xpath on html)

Comment: Thank you that works! I don't understand how though so I'll go and read about [preceding-sibling.